# clustering algorithm with curve fitting

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, cluster-analysis, curve-fitting

I have a cloud of points. Points can be segregated into cluster, each cluster is well fitted with one regression curve (a straight line).

I want the number of clusters so that points are best fitted by the corresponding curves. There is no a priori knowledge of the number of clusters.

Aim is to find clusters and associated regression curves (second is obvious as soon as you have the clusters).

EDIT::
for determining the number of cluster, I know a bit of BIC criteria. This may be a way to start with an approx known number of clusters.

Comment: I think this would be better fit for a mathematics-oriented exchange site...

Comment: this page has more readers, and there are a lot of clustering questions around but tks on your advice

Comment: I am looking for methods in clustering, and there are a lot of tagged posts on clustering in SO, so that it seems totally relevant to SO

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about clustering and statistical models; should be on CrossValidated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Scott Gaffney](http://labs.yahoo.com/author/gaffney/)'s work on [Curve Clustering](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~sgaffney/). I had to opportunity to work with Scott for a year in graduate school and his Matlab Toolbox that he provides on his site works pretty well.

Also, consult his dissertation on implementing curve clustering based on polynomial curves and splines.

Answer (score 0):

the underlying notion is Regression Clustering. Some approaches uses likelihood, as for example in second link on [ggle search here](https://www.google.fr/search?q=regression%20clustering&oq=regression%20clustering&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l3j69i62l2.4076j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).